# How to include checkbox validation on visual basic?

Tags: validation, checkbox

if **no checkboxes are checked,**

then messagebox.show("Please select at least one checkbox")

How can I do this on vb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that if you are having two checkboxes means the validation must be....

```
if ((checkbox1.checked=false) and (checkbox2.checked=false) ) then
  msgbox "please select atleast one checkbox"
else
  //the code you wanted to do
end If
```

This will do the think what you asked!